# pip: How to deal with different python versions to install Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have different versions of Python installed on my Ubuntu machine (2.7.11, 2.7.12, 3.5). I would like to install Flask on the 2.7.12 as it used by Apache.

I have three pip{version} in my PATH which are: pip, pip2, and pip2.7. How do I know which one is for which python version.

I have already read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) but it didn't help my case as I need to differentiate between minor version number 2.7.11 and 2.7.12.

One thing is that I tried pip{version} install Flask for all three pips but the 2.7.12 still can't import Flask.

Any help is much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Rather a comment than an answer, but this is what `virtualenv` is exactly for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should always create virtualenvs for your projects](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/#virtualenv). You can create one like

```
virtualenv -p <path/to/python2.7.12> <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

inside that virtualenv `pip` and `python` will always select the right interpreter and path.

Comment: It seems best for now. I just wanted to use the main actual system python not virtual but I think I have to.

Comment: You are using the system python. But you are isolating all `pip` installed packages from your main system (which would require you to use `sudo pip` and could mess up your system).

Answer (score 1):

You can find it out by trying to run this: `pip --version`. Output will be something like this: `pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`. This way we can see that it is for `python2.7` in my case.

Comment: --version is not giving the minor version number. Also, I get same site-packages paths for both 2.7.11 and 2.7.12. But, if I try "iimport site;  site.getsitepackages()" I will get different paths. Still struggling.